# HTML form overlay on a widget contained in a div

Tags: css, html

I am a novice when it comes to modern HTML (HTML5/CSS/Ajax/JQuery, etc). I have a web application that is using a Google Earth plugin like tool called Cesium. Like Google Earth, it allows you to view and interact with a global map of the earth. Cesium runs as a widget in a div container. The canvas takes up a whole div element. In my app it takes the entire width and most of the body.

I have a need for a small text search form that exists outside of this div container.

It consists of one form input and a couple of buttons. I would like this to sit on top (overlay) the div container that contains the cesium widget. I would like it to only take up a small section in the upper left corner, overlaying the cesium widget. I would be great if the background, underneath the form input field and buttons were transparent.

Below is a small sample of the HTML and CSS. I know it will involve some CSS but as I said I’m a novice.

Any helpful hints on slick ways for doing this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```css
body
{
  background-color : #000000;
  margin : 0;
  margin-bottom : 20px;
  margin-top : 20px;
  width : 100%;
}

.textSearchSection
{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  height : 5%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}

.textInputField
{
 width : 200px;
}
.map
{
  height : 95%;
  overflow : hidden;
  width : 100%;
}

.button
{
    width : 80px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css">
    <script>
    var cesiumViewer = null; //declare these here so processTextInputForm() has access to them
 </script>
  </head>

  <body>
 <!--I want this to semi transparently overlay the cesiumContainer div, and only take a minumum amount of width-->
    <div class="textSearchSection" id="textSearchSection">
        <form id="searchForm" name="searcForm">
            <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" class="textInputField" onchange="somejavascriptfunction()"/>
   <input id="searchButton" type="button" value="Text Search" class="button" onclick="somejavascriptfunction()">
   <input id="clearButton" type="button" value="Clear" class="button" onclick="somejavascriptfunction()">
        </form>
 </div>
 
 <!--This is the div that contains the cesium application-->
    <div class="map" id="cesiumContainer"></div>

 <script>
 cesiumViewer = new CesiumViewer(); //This can't be created until after the cesiumContainer id is declared in the div.
 </script>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually moving the form div (searchContainer below)  into the cesiumContainer div, and using CSS z-index attributes as shown below (searchOverlay set to 1, map set to 0) does the trick. So it is a child of the cesiumContainer div.

```css
.map
{
  height : 100%;
  overflow : hidden;
  width : 100%;
  z-index : 0;
}

.searchOverlay
{
  left : 10;
  position : relative;
  top : 33;
  width : 50%;
  z-index : 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="map" id="cesiumContainer">
      <div class="searchOverlay" id="searchContainer">
        <input class="textSearch" id="searchText" name="searchText" type="text" onchange="processTextInputForm()"/>
          &nbsp;
        <input class="button" id="searchButton" type="button" value="Search" onclick="processTextInputForm()" onkeydown="searchEnter(event)">
          &nbsp;
        <input class="button" id="searchButton" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearResults()">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to move the `textSearchSection`  so that it nests inside a parent container as a sibling element to `cesiumContainer`:

```
<div id="parentContainer">
    <div class="map" id="cesiumContainer"></div>
    <div class="textSearchSection" id="textSearchSection">...</div>
</div>
```

Then you can style `parentContainer` so that it is exactly the same size as `cesiumContainer` and style `textSearchSection` with:

```
#textSearchSection {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 12;
}
```